# Сервер неправильно отображает js файл

Tags: javascript, django, nginx

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Пижу сайт на django с nginx сервером. Все статические файлы отображаются нормально, кроме js. В браузерной консоли выскакивает ошибка:
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/static/js/reg.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Почему то, js файл отображается с типом text/plain, а не application/javascript.

Comment: `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` пробовали?

Comment: Да, увы, не помогает

Comment: Конфиг nginx в студию

Comment: В слове "пижу" опечатка "ш-ж", или пропущена буква "з"? В зависимости от этого, смысл вoпроса кардинально меняется :)